# How to group mysql query results by hour?

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

Ill show you what I am doing and then what I ment to.

Now:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `total`, `date` FROM `Events` GROUP BY HOUR(`date`)
```

This is returning something like that:

```
date       | Count
1389105597 | 125
```

This is what I would like to have, but i dont know how:

```
 date       | Count
 00:01      | 10
 01:02      | 13
 02:03      | 3
 (...)
 23:00      | 30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates appear to be a unix timestamp - an integer representing the number of seconds since Jan 1,1970. They are *NOT* a mysql date/time string, which is what most of MySQL's date/time functions expect.

Try the following:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total, HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) AS hour
...
GROUP BY HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`))
```

This will convert your timestamp back to a native mysql date/time value, which you can use to extract the hours from.

Comment: You made it! Ive add this now: `CONCAT(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), ':00-', HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date))+1, ':00') AS Hours` and looks exactly like I expected :) And what about performance? About this conversions

Comment: there's some conversion overhead. generally speaking, it's better to store your dates/times as native mysql date and time values, because it's fairly efficient to do these hour/date/whatever conversions from the native types. adding in the from_unixtime conversion forces that conversion EVERY time you run your select, which can kill performance on large tables. The advantage with unix timestamps is that they're simple ints, and if you don't need to extract date components from them, they're very space efficient to store

Comment: I see ;) maybe it is better rethink about it for this particular case